# How to get value for Min data only

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

my query as below will get result as in the picture

```
SELECT Dept,
       Item,       
       Month,
       OpenQty,
       OpenVal
FROM   StockTransaction
WHERE  year = 2016 and
       month between 1 and 10
```

[image: This is the result from my query above]

actually the result i want are **only the minimum month for each dept and item** will hold the **openqty** and **openval** value. Other than that will hold zero value.

[image]

how to write query to get the result as above picture?

Answer (score 3):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT Dept, Item, Month,
       (CASE WHEN row_number() over (partition by dept, item order by month) = 1
             THEN OpenQty ELSE 0
        END) as OpenQty,
       (CASE WHEN row_number() over (partition by dept, item order by month) = 1
             THEN OpenVal ELSE 0
        END) as OpenVal
FROM StockTransaction
WHERE year = 2016 and
      month between 1 and 10;
```

Comment: help alot! tq so much